# build error with c++ - ‘find_if’ is not a member of ‘std'

Tags: c++, build

While building a project, I get this cryptic error:

‘find_if’ is not a member of ‘std'

find_if() is used this way: std::find_if(...).

Any idea where it could come from ?

Comment: Have you included the `<algorithm>` header?

Comment: lol that's a lot of people reminding me how dumb I am. Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

add the  inclusion:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

to your implementation file.

Answer (score 15):

Did you include the header

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Answer (score 14):

You need `#include <algorithm>`

Answer (score 14):

Include the `<algorithm>` header file:

```
#include <algorithm>
```